# Jest test fails in GitHub Actions but passes locally

Tags: github, jwt, nestjs, github-actions

There's only one test that's failing with this message 'ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] secretOrPrivateKey must have a value ... at JwtService.sign', which I find weird, because a lot of tests cases use this service too, and locally the test passes correctly.

Here's the log of the CI pipeline in debug mode https://github.com/mateomaza/todo-app-api/actions/runs/7005451263/job/19055682105

I have my .env values in GitHub Secrets, that shouldn't be the issue: [Repository Secrets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eL6Bp.png)

Here's my .yml file:

```
name: Backend CI

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Check Out Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 18

        env:
          MONGO_URI: ${{secrets.MONGO_URI}}
          JWT_SECRET_KEY: ${{secrets.JWT_SECRET_KEY}}
          REDIS_HOST: ${{secrets.REDIS_HOST}}
          REDIS_PORT: ${{secrets.REDIS_PORT}}
          REDIS_PASSWORD: ${{secrets.REDIS_PASSWORD}}
          REDIS_TLS: ${{secrets.REDIS_TLS}}
          NODE_ENV: 'test'

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm install

      - name: Run Tests
        run: npm run test
```

And here's the 'it block' where the issue is happening (just in case):

```
it('should refresh access token', async () => {
    const mockRefreshToken = 'mock-new-token';
    authService.verifyRefreshToken.mockResolvedValue(mockCreatedUser as User);
    const response = await request(app.getHttpServer())
      .post('/api/auth/refresh')
      .set('Cookie', [`refresh_token=${mockRefreshToken}`])
      .expect(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    expect(response.body).toHaveProperty('access_token');
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you got is likely complaining about missing `JWT_SECRET_KEY` in your `Run Tests` step.

While you did set env variables at the `Setup Node.js` step, it is only confined into the scope of that particular step. The `Run Tests` step did not get the env variables.

One possible solution is to move your env variables up to the job level:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Env is now available for all steps within the 'build' job
    env:
      MONGO_URI: ${{secrets.MONGO_URI}}
      JWT_SECRET_KEY: ${{secrets.JWT_SECRET_KEY}}
      REDIS_HOST: ${{secrets.REDIS_HOST}}
      REDIS_PORT: ${{secrets.REDIS_PORT}}
      REDIS_PASSWORD: ${{secrets.REDIS_PASSWORD}}
      REDIS_TLS: ${{secrets.REDIS_TLS}}
      NODE_ENV: 'test'

    steps:
      - name: Check Out Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 18

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm install

      - name: Run Tests
        run: npm run test
```

Comment: this was it, thank u so much, sorry i can't upvote :s

Comment: Glad it helped, please accept the answer so others know it worked. Cheers